# Anchor dynamic element with click event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically add an anchor element through Javascript.  The problem I have is the onclick event is not firing.  I believe the problem is how I am generating the HTML.  I am creating an array and then push my HTML code to the array.  After I have created my output I am joining the array and then adding it to the div tag I have.

```js
var itemLink = new Object();
itemLink.LinkName = "Edit User";
itemLink.LinkListClass = "";
itemLink.LinkListRole = "";
itemLink.LinkFunction = function() {
  //do something specific with rowItem variable
  alert(rowItem);
}

var aTag = document.createElement("a");
aTag.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
aTag.innerHTML = itemLink.LinkName;
aTag.setAttribute('href', '#');
var rowItem = 'abc1111'; //would be setting the rowId or some sort of identifier
aTag.onclick = itemLink.LinkFunction;


var output = [];

output.push('<table>');
output.push('<thead>');
output.push('<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>');
output.push('</thead>');
output.push('<tbody>');
output.push('<tr><td>col1 data</td><td>col2 data</td></tr>');
output.push('</tbody></table>')

var d1 = document.createElement('div');
d1.appendChild(aTag);
output.push(d1.innerHTML);


var mainView = document.getElementById('mainViewer');
mainView.innerHTML = output.join('');
```

```html
<div id="mainViewer"></div>
```

When I generate the output without the use of the array and joining of the output, the anchor element gets created and the onclick event works just fine.

Any ideas?
I will have multiple anchor links and I don't want to hardcode the function name.  I want the onclick event to fire whatever function the itemLink Object has set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the problem? You bind a function to a temp DOM element, then append its html, **not its events** (that's how `innerHTML` works). So when a link appended to the DOM, it's a **different** DOM link, so although the link **looks** the same it's not.

So, what is the solution? to push a DOM element instead of string, something like this:

```js
//var itemLink = new Object();
//itemLink.LinkName = "Edit User";
//itemLink.LinkListClass = "";
//itemLink.LinkListRole = "";
//itemLink.LinkFunction = function() {
//do something specific with rowItem variable
//alert(rowItem);
//}

var itemLink = {
  LinkName: "Edit User",
  LinkListClass: "",
  LinkListRole: "",
  LinkFunction: function() {
    //do something specific with rowItem variable
    alert(rowItem);
  }
};

var aTag = document.createElement("a");
aTag.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
aTag.innerHTML = itemLink.LinkName;
aTag.setAttribute('href', '#');
var rowItem = 'abc1111'; //would be setting the rowId or some sort of identifier
aTag.onclick = itemLink.LinkFunction;


var output = [];

output.push('<table>');
output.push('<thead>');
output.push('<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>');
output.push('</thead>');
output.push('<tbody>');
output.push('<tr><td>col1 data</td><td>col2 data</td></tr>');
output.push('</tbody></table>')

var mainView = document.getElementById('mainViewer');
mainView.innerHTML = output.join('');

var d1 = document.createElement('div');
d1.appendChild(aTag);
mainView.appendChild(d1)
```

```html
<div id="mainViewer"></div>
```

Thanks to [@David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) for his comment :)

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully it's clearer (Feel free to edit :)). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  @Mosh how did you edit the code to look much nicer?  Is there a FAQ or something for that I can read up on?

Comment: I just found another way.  That was to add an anchor element and just specify the onclick event.  output.push('<a href="#" onclick="(' + menulinks[j].LinkFunction + ')(\'' + rowItem +  '\')"><span>' + menulinks[j].LinkName + '</span></a>');

Comment: @foop [stackoverflow snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Glad you found another solution. Just note that this solution will work for you as long as the param is primitive (boolean, string etc.) but you couldn't do this is non primitive object (nested object)

Comment: Also, I updated my answer with a better (my opinion) way to declare an object. Also, if you are using jQuery, you can do this much easier and clearer.